# Java.lang.AssertionError in a SortedArrayList

Tags: java, android, junit

So I'm making an Contact Manager App in Android. My professor send us a JUnit test so we can know if our code is working correctly. Now every method has passed the test except the iterator test which fails the test. It appears to be a **java.lang.AssertionError** and I cant seem to figure out a way of fixing it. If you could see the error and point it out to me would be awesome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: ok I updated the question with the Stack Trace. Thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

You haven't implemented your `iterator(int)` method

```
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new ListIterator<E>();
}
```

to do anything about the index. So in your test

```
@Test
public void testIteratorInt() {
    Iterator<String> iter = this.list.iterator(0);
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertTrue(iter.next().equals("Amy"));

    iter = this.list.iterator(2);
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertTrue(iter.next().equals("Bob"));
}
```

the `ListIterator` returned still starts off pointing to the first element, instead of the third, which is `Bob`.

You could simply move the iterator forward twice and then test

```
iter.next();
iter.next();
assertTrue(iter.next().equals("Bob"));
```

Or actually implement the `iterator(int)` method as you see fit.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I'm still in the learning process of the iterators so I completely ignore this case

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming off the second assert in `testIteratorInt`:

```
@Test
public void testIteratorInt() {
    Iterator<String> iter = this.list.iterator(0);
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());
    assertTrue(iter.next().equals("Amy"));

    iter = this.list.iterator(2);
    assertTrue(iter.hasNext());    
    assertTrue(iter.next().equals("Bob"));//ASSERT ERROR THROWN HERE

}
```

The `iterator(int index)` method needs to be implemented such that it sets the current position when it's passed in like the above unit test. Something like this should work:

```
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator(int index) {
    ListIterator<E> iter = new ListIterator<E>();
    iter.currentPosition = index;
    return iter;
}
```

Tested and working on my machine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still in the process of fully understanding the iterators so the help is greatly appreciated

Comment: No prob, for more information on iterators check out the Javadocs for collecitons: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html